# C# memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory, appfabric

I am testing appfabric cache performance. To do this, from my local machine , I am hitting the cache host on the LAN. This cache host is running on Windows Server 2008 and except from the bare essentials has nothing installed on it. It has 8 gigs of RAM. It is also a VMware virtual server,

As soon as I hit the cache host, i can see the memory being used increases. But something very fishy is going on somewhere. the total primary data bytes that is being used is 1.5 Gigs. The Object size is 1,744 bytes (using ANTS profiler).The total object count is 2,521,451. I have disabled eviction. But, this is interesting, as soon as the server hits the throttled state, I can see that server's RAM is being used at 7.72 Gigs, but apart from the distributed cache using 1.8 gigs there is no other application thats using such a high quantity of RAM.

I am using Visual studio 2010 , and I am inserting and reading the objects in parallel

The question that I wanted to ask is :

Where is my memory going? The server in the throttled state says I am using 7.72 gigs of the alloted memory whereas in the task manager, i can see that barely 3 Gigs are being used (if i add all the running process's memory)

Comment: Are you running VS on the server? And how much memory is being used before you start / after you stop your application?

Comment: What columns are your memory usage numbers coming from? Because 2,521,451 objects time 1744 bytes gives 4GB.

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but since you are using this much data, you might be interested in a more efficient (and free) serializer. Let me know if so...

Comment: @Mark, the server is the VMWare Virtual Machine.. I am running my Load Test Application on the client. There are no applications other than process monitor and AppFabric installed on the VMware Virtual Machine. As soon as i start this VM the memory that's being used is 854 MB.. When i start to test the application, the memory increases.  but when I look at the status of the VM memory when the cache enters the throttled state, its 7.7 Gigs.. not sure where my meory is going

Comment: @marc Gravell.. thanks for the support.. sure I would like to have it .. thanks

Comment: @Gagan - protobuf-net; in every test I'v seen it stomps all over DCS/NDCS/BF/XS etc, both in terms of bandwidth and CPU.

Comment: Have you made sure all IDisposable objects are calling Dispose when they're done?  I assume so, but have seen similar behavior to your memory issue when that didn't happen.

Comment: Marc>  I'm interested in a more efficient and free serializer!  : )

Answer (score 3):

Gagan, if you're still having this issue, can you download SysInternals' Process Monitor?  You can find it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).  Run it, and add columns for memory private bytes, working set, and virtual size.  Peak private bytes and working set wouldn't hurt, either, and there are other memory columns you can add for fun : )

Task Manager doesn't give you the virtual size (Windows 7 lets you add Commit Size, don't know if Server 2008 also has that).  This should give you a clearer picture of where the memory is going.

Let us know if that helps or you need further help pinning down where your memory is going!

Comment: Thanks for the info @ James B.. I was already using that... I think that there is a memory leak somewhere with MS AppFabric ... i have informed the guys @ MS about this .. thanks for the info.. guys !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on this, as it's not clear in your question where you're seeing the different RAM usage amounts (VMWare guest or host).

When running VMWare Server on Server 2008, the memory usage reported by Task Manager on the host does not take into account the Virtual Machines individual usages. I noticed this a while ago, and am not sure if it's a bug/known issue/by design behaviour.

**Example**: I have 3 VMs running on my Server 2008 machine, each running a different variant of Windows, with applications running. Nothing is running on the host, other than the Virtual Machines at the moment. Task manager on the host reports ~2GB RAM used, whereas the guests are using at least 1GB each.

Can you clarify exactly where your RAM usage numbers are coming from?

Comment: . I am looking at the task manager of my server, which is a VM , running windows 2008 server..for my RAM usage numbers. The other specific numbers related to cache are from AppFabric Perfmon Counters

Comment: I am looking at Task Manager on the guest (the virtual machine running on the host).  Also, we are not running VMWare on a windows server, we are running the enterprise ESXi 

I think you are talking about a problem with memory usage in the virtualization on the host, whereas I am talking about a memory leak in AppFabric on the guest.

Comment: Ah, OK, apologies. I couldn't quite work out exactly what your scenario was.

Comment: @jayMz..thats ok.. no worries :)